# Generic Type in java: How to define a function with multiple different type returned

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

```
@Service
public class Animal {
   public String name;
}
@Service
public class Dog extends Animal {
   public String name;
}

@Service
public class Cat extends Animal {
   public String name;
}
```

In spring boot project, I wanna obtain one specific bean by using ApplicationContext provided by spring framework, here is a simple example i write to illustrate:

```
@Component
public class AnimalLocator implements ApplicationContextAware {
   private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
   @Override
   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
      if (PayServiceLocator.applicationContext == null) {
         PayServiceLocator.applicationContext = applicationContext;
      }
   }

   public <T extends Animal> T getService(String name) {
      if("Cat".equals(name) {
        applicationContext.getBean(name, Cat.class);
      }
      if("Dog".equals(name) {
        applicationContext.getBean(name, Dog.class);
      }
   }
}
```

However, exceptions was prompted by the compiler:

[image]

the mosaic part should be Dog or cat. I thought it should work, since T has already extended the Animal class, but it doesn't ,so does anyone has any ideas about it? Thank you!

Comment: your code doesn't represent what you actually test. getService() vs getPayService(), missing return in the method of the code but according to the error message it is another issue. Please edit your post to make it clear.

Comment: `return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name, Cat.class);`

Comment: @Lino I don't think. T is already infered from the declared returned type : `<T extends Animal> `

Comment: @davidxxx it's needed, as the `getBean()` method will be infered to either `Cat.class` or `Dog.class` but never to the actual generic type  `T`

Comment: @Lino Agreed for `getBean()` . But the method is declared `<T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType)`. The return type of T is infered from the target and the target is `<T extends Animal>`.

Comment: I vote to close : unclear.

Comment: @davidxxx then the call to `getBean()` can not work, as the class you'd pass to it would not be equal to the type `T` (either java complains about not the right type, or it will `T getBean` will get infered to the passed `Class` type)

Comment: Pass in the `Animal` class you want as a parameter, then simply `return applicationContext.getBean(animalClass, getSimpleName(), animalClass);`.

Comment: @davidxxx seems like we talked past each other. I agree with the last comment, that should work without the need for casting :)

Comment: return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name, Cat.class) is good, no more compiler problems occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using bean class to access bean instance, it's straight forward to pass class as parameter:

```
public <T extends Animal> T getPayService(String name, Class<T> payClass) {
   return applicationContext.getBean(name, payClass);
}
```

Comment: So why would it not work with the actual code ?  Passing a Cat  or a Dog class as parameter or inline them should have the same behavior.

Comment: In his original version he has to cast to `T`, as the compiler cannot figure out which `T` it is dealing with @davidxxx

Comment: It works. But is there any other better suggestions, because the function getService( getPayService previously, typo) is used to find out which service is gonna be used, which means i don't get Class<T> info

Comment: Then you have to cast. `return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name, Cat.class);
`. This way you defer the error to runtime

Answer (score 1):

`T` in `getPayService` will extend `Animal`, of course. This means that code calling it with another type won't compile:

```
Fruit fruit = animalLocator.getPayService("Banana")
```

To illustrate *your current problem*, look at this:

```
Cat cat = animalLocator.getPayService("Dog");
```

`T` is `Cat` in this case, but your code would be returning a `Dog`.

To circumvent the compiler error, you can add a type cast:

```
return (T) applicationContext.getBean(...
```

But this would still not be safe because the compiler will still be unable to guarantee that the actual return type will be what `T` is in the context of the caller at runtime, and the caller would be having a class cast exception.

If we can assume that `getBean` is a safe call, then you should change your method to this implementation:

```
public <T extends Animal> T getPayService(String name, Class<T> cls) {
   return applicationContext.getBean(name, cls);
}
```

This doesn't change a lot from the caller's perspective, but hinges on the fact (or assumption) that `applicationContext.getBean(name, cls);` will return an object of type `T`. This means your code is as type-safe as `getBean` is, but the compiler is happy with that.

Comment: Yes, after reading many tutorials about this, I found Locator supplied by ApplicationContext is not as safe as Dependency Injection(IOC). But when it comes to the case i met,  type cast is the way to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can Autowired all your Animal instances in a Map instead of coding your if/else :

```
@Service("Animal")
public class Animal {
    public String name;
}
@Service("Dog")
    public class Dog extends Animal {
}
@Service("Cat")
    public class Cat extends Animal {
}
```

And in your AnimalLocator :

```
@Component
public class AnimalLocator {

   @Autowired
   private Map<String,Animal> animals;

   public <T extends Animal> T getService(String name) {
      return this.animals.get(name);
   }
}
```